# data object can't be accessed from <td> if the html table isn't enclosed in <table></table>

Tags: vuejs3

the code below produces this error:
`[Vue warn]: Property "character" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.  at <App>`
And no table row gets rendered.

```html
<div>
   <p v-if="characters.length === 0">Characters are unavailable at this time.</p>
   <div v-else>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr v-for="character in characters">
            <td>{{ character.name }}</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </div>
   <button v-on:click="thisShouldBeGet">Display Characters</button>
</div>
...
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script>
const { createApp } = Vue;
const app = createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      mockResponse: [{
          name: 'Jeff'
        },
        {
          name: 'Britta'
        },
        {
          name: 'This fuckin guy'
        },
        {
          name: 'Some other dude'
        }
      ],
      characters: []
    }
  },

  methods: {
    thisShouldBeGet() {
      this.characters.push(...this.mockResponse)
    }
  }

})
</script>
```

The mentioned error is due to invalid HTML in the code above.
There should be a `<table>` tag before the `<thead>`.
There should be a `</table>` tag after `</tbody>` tag.

```html
<table>
   <tbody>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr v-for="character in characters">
            <td>{{ character.name }}</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now the HTML is valid. Vue no longer console logs the error and the table rows are properly rendered.

As @Moritz Ringler kindly pointed out: I am using Vue as a library dropped from the CDN link so Vue is working on the DOM nodes generated by the browser. So writing valid HTML is of the utmost importance.
Still, I would like for someone to hold my hand even more gently and walk me through what transpired to produce that error in even more depth.

Comment: Hmm, my guess for the downvote: horribly formatted code, no snippet/playground, unclear text (it says the code is corrected, later it says that the solution was to add table tags, but there are no table tags in the code - so what was corrected?), and it seems like you are asking why it matters to write valid HTML, which is a question that really answers itself. Also, it misses the important part, which is that you are not pre-compiling the template (I think), so Vue will not work on the HTML, but on the DOM nodes generated by the browser, which depends even more on valid HTML.

Comment: @MoritzRingler My apologies for all the formatting/phrasing blunders and thank you for having taken the time to answer.   
You are spot on, I am using Vue as a CDN script and you already gave me the bread crumb trail to follow. Vue works on the DOM nodes.

Comment: I corrected to the best of my abilities all the mistakes you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: That's great. Though you should be able to format code correctly, and supply code without typos and syntax errors - mockResponse vs mockResonse (no "p"), missing `this` in `this.mockResponse`, `methods` was given with function parens). Finding those bugs should not be part of answering your question. Supplying code without errors is part of [the effort expected when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Adding a snippet is a good way to make sure your code runs. I fixed those errors in your question.

Comment: My apologies for letting those typos slip my mind and thank you so much for your efforts and advice (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't much to it except what was already said, but since you asked for a more detailed explanation:

When a browser finds invalid HTML, it tries to fix it. For example, when a tag is never closed, the browser will close it automatically at a position that seems right. In your case, you are using table content tags outside a table, and the browser just removes those. Note though that the behavior is vendor-specific, some browsers might handle it differently.

Have a look at what will be left when the browser is done (minus newlines and some spaces):

```js
const node = document.getElementById('container')
console.log(node.innerHTML.replaceAll("\n", '').replace(/  +/g, ' '))
```

```html
<div id="container">
  before <br>
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr v-for="character in characters">
        <td>{{ character.name }}</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
  <br> after
</div>
```

Since you are using Vue directly on HTML content, Vue only sees the code after the browser has processed it, i.e. after all table content tags have been removed - including the `v-for` - leaving you with a sole `{{ character.name }}`, which will lead to the error.

The browser will also remove casing from attribute names, so `modelValue` becomes `modelvalue`, which is the most common annoyance when using Vue on browser code.

Typically, the solution is to put the code into the component template, so that Vue can process it before it is altered by the browser. This even works with the invalid HTML from the question:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const App = { 
  template: `
     <p v-if="characters.length === 0">Characters are unavailable at this time.</p>
     <div v-else>
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr v-for="character in characters">
              <td>{{ character.name }}</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
     </div>
     <button v-on:click="thisShouldBeGet">Display Characters</button>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      mockResponse: [{
          name: 'Jeff'
        },
        {
          name: 'Britta'
        },
        {
          name: 'This fuckin guy'
        },
        {
          name: 'Some other dude'
        }
      ],
      characters: []
    }
  },

  methods: {
    thisShouldBeGet() {
      this.characters.push(...this.mockResponse)
    }
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

But, in case it isn't obvious, writing invalid HTML is something you should try to avoid.

Comment: But of course! That's why when I replaced `<td>` and `<tr>` with, respectively, `<ul>` and `<li>` during my naïve attempts at "investigating" the issue, the `v-for` "magically" produced the desired output -> because the browser must have removed the "`<table>`less" `<thead>` `<tr>` `<th>` `<tbody>` tags (along with their closing counterparts) and kept the `<ul>` and the `<li>` tags. Thank you so much, it kept boething me to not understand what **exactly** happened, at a lower level than just seeing an empty section where the rows should've been. Now I understand what happened, thanks to you.